# Having trouble with deleting profiles on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, screensaver, profile-manager

[image: profiles]

Initially hi everyone, im having trouble with deleting profiles. I've searched but I couldn’t find anything. I got so many profiles installed on my mac and when i try to delete them the minus button is not active therefore i can't change my screen saver options etc like as;

[image: screen saver]

as you can see i can't change my screen saver timer

System info:
macOS Monterey Version 12.0.1
MacBook Pro 2016 15"
2.6 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 processor
16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 memory
Intel HD Graphics 530
AMD Radeon pro 450

Comment: Is this a company Mac (or a Mac managed centrally)?

Comment: No its my personal mac

Comment: But the Profiles preference pane says "This Mac is supervised and managed by Culture Amp."

Comment: i have no idea why is it says that

Comment: Who did you buy the Mac from?

Comment: from a store who buys and sells MacBooks

Comment: I did a quick research my problem is about MDM right ? Should i contact with "Culture Amp" company or do you guys have any recommendations ?